Is there a "Use all Daedalus enchantments" Minor Prophecy for each of the Nocturnal Arms?
The Fated List of Minor Prophecies seems to start out with the "The Witch's Staff" prophecy for using all the possible Daedalus enchantments at least once for said staff.
Is there a "Use all Daedalus enchantments" Minor Prophecy for each of the Nocturnal Arms?
Or is it "not as of v.103687".
Wanting to know because I liked the Staff and only switched to the Umbral Flames to get the Book of Shadows entry. Can I switch to something else now that I've possibly got every "Easy" "achievement" for the Flames?

Yes, there is such a Prophecy, at least for the Moonstone Axe. It appears that the reveal condition is to apply 3 different enchantments.
